# translation of scientific names

Tags: zoology, entomology, terminology, nomenclature, etymology

I am trying to determine the "translated" meanings (not seeking the common names) of different insects, (presently some bees and wasps).  Does anyone know of a printed or internet resource that defines the various names. I have one for plants, but not for animals.  Knowing the (English) meaning of the Latin / Greek/ etc. is often very informative -- IF I can find it.

I can give more specifics if you want.

Thanks.

Glen B
Olympia WA, USA

Comment: All you need to do is use a Latin/English and/or Greek/English dictionary. This is not really related to biology but linguistics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about nomenclature and the meanings of words in dead languages, not biology.

Comment: what OP meant by latin and greek names is the binomial nomenclature (which for historical reasons is in latin and greek)

Answer (score 1):

Glen, sometimes there are many species that have same colloquial name. For e.g. *frog* includes hundreds of species. If you require high level of detail, you may need to look for more comprehensive lists.

There are zoology dictionaries such as [this](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199233410.001.0001/acref-9780199233410). I think it should serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple resources that are in use as far as I can see from a quick google search. You would find the Integrated Taxonomic Information System [(ITIS)](http://www.itis.gov/) quite useful. It includes details on scientific papers published about a specific species.